# При добавление li из js клонированием, не сохраняется нужный порядок. Как его установить?

Tags: javascript

Всем добрый день.

Вот моя поделка (п.с. сори без адаптации под разрешения)

Попробуйте вводить 1 enter, 2 enter, 3 enter и т.д. после 1 и 2 ввод отрабатывают корректно, однако уже на 3 вводе, 1 и 2 меняются местами, мне же необходимо чтобы всё продолжалось так как на первых двух вводах.

1) Как правильно оформить код и какой метод использовать чтобы вывод был от первого и до конечно снизу вверх?

2) Как правильно удалять текущую вкладку т.к. с удалением тоже проблемы?

```js
// By pressing the enter, the value of the entered data is determined in the input,
//  new Li are created to which this value is transmitted ________________________

try {
    const enter = input.addEventListener ("keypress", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            const text = document.getElementById('input').value.trim();
            document.getElementById('input').value = '';
            
            let newLi = document.getElementById('tameplate');
            let liClone = newLi.cloneNode(true);
            newLi.parentNode.appendChild(liClone);
            newLi.classList.add("block");
            let textP = document.getElementById('inputText');
            textP.innerHTML = text;  
        }
    });
} catch {
    alert('Please refresh the page');
}


// By clicking, the current 'li' will be deleted.__________________________________

const del = () => {
    let newLi = document.getElementById('tameplate');
    newLi.remove();
};
```

```css
@import url(reset.css);

body {
    font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    min-width: 230px;
    max-width: 550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-weight: 300;
}
header {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
h1 {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.15);
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.new-todo {
    padding: 16px 16px 16px 60px;
    border: none;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    box-shadow: -3px 8px 12px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    color: inherit;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.new {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 60px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.tameplate {
    display: none;
}
.block {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.spin {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 496px;
    top: 17px;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #af5b5e;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    z-index: 1;
}
.block:hover .spin {
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Task2</title>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>todos</h1>
        <input id="input" class="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" value="" >
        <ul class="unordered-list">
            <li class="tameplate new-todo new" id="tameplate">
                <p id="inputText"></p>
                <i class="fa fa-times spin" id="spin" onclick="del()"></i>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Спасибо

Comment: Основная ваша проблема в том, что вы дублируете id на странице. Т.е. после первого выполнения программы, у вас на страницы будет уже два элемента с id="tameplate".

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// By pressing the enter, the value of the entered data is determined in the input,
//  new Li are created to which this value is transmitted ________________________

try {
  let template = document.querySelector('#template').content; //.content - потому что всё содержимое шаблона завёрнуто в невидимый `document-fragment`
  let li = template.querySelector('.tameplate');
  let ul = document.querySelector('.unordered-list');

  const enter = input.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      const text = document.getElementById('input').value.trim();
      document.getElementById('input').value = '';

      let newLi = li.cloneNode(true);

      ul.appendChild(newLi);
      newLi.classList.add("block");
      let textP = newLi.querySelector('#inputText');
      textP.innerHTML = text;
    }
  });
} catch {
  alert('Please refresh the page');
}


// By clicking, the current 'li' will be deleted.__________________________________

const del = (f) => {
  f.remove();
};
```

```css
@import url(reset.css);
body {
  font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-weight: 300;
}

header {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

h1 {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.15);
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.new-todo {
  padding: 16px 16px 16px 60px;
  border: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  box-shadow: -3px 8px 12px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  color: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.new {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 60px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.tameplate {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.spin {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 496px;
  top: 17px;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #af5b5e;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  z-index: 1;
}

.block:hover .spin {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Task2</title>
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>todos</h1>
    <input id="input" class="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" value="">
    <ul class="unordered-list">

    </ul>
  </header>
  <template id='template'>
      <li class="tameplate new-todo new">
                <p id="inputText"></p>
                <i class="fa fa-times spin" id="spin" onclick="del(this.parentNode)"></i>
       </li>
   </template>
</body>

</html>
```

Для шаблонов в **HTML** предусмотрен специальный **тег - "template"**. Насчёт удаления: в html в **onclick** надо передать **this.parentNode**

Comment: Очень круто, спасибо, получилось однако я не разобрался в некоторых вещах в частности 
1) Для чего необходимо было находить let template ?
2) Что это за аргумент у функции del (f) как это именно работает? И что значит - this.parentNode? (я конечно это буду гуглить но сразу отмечу тут что не понятно.

Comment: @Mark, а как по-другому достучаться к блоку? `f` - можно назвать как хотите, это было нужно, чтобы передать `this.parentNode`. Насчёт последнего - `this` указывает на элемент, на котором произошло действие. А через `.parentNode` мы добираемся к его родителю, т.к. надо удалить его, а не `this(кнопка-крестик)`

Comment: а подскажите ещё пож. если нужно не использовать в html вызов по клику как это реализовать только в Js файле, с учётом возможной более глубокой вложенности для ' i '? И так же не по теме но если знаете возможно тоже подскажите, нужно ещё чтобы после каждого ввода инфы или удаления вкладочки, чтобы в консоли был вывод массива с todo листа?

Comment: @Mark, если без `HTML`, то удалить можно так: `ul.addEventListener('click', () => { let target = event.target;
       if (!target.classList.contains('fa')) return;
       target.parentNode.remove();
});`

2)Насчёт вывода в консоль не понял

Comment: После каждого нажатия кнопки или после каждого удаления вкладки, необходимо чтобы в консоль браузера выводился массив с todo листом, я так понимаю массив где каждый объект это то что было введено в отдельную вкладку. Знаете как это можно реализовать?

Comment: @Mark, что сложного в добавлении элемента в массив?

Comment: Добавил код по удалению, всё корректно отрабатывает без вызовы функции из html, однако не понятно, как это работает... нужно учить DOM, совсем ещё с ним не знаком(

С массивом в целом более менее есть идеи, однако чтобы был вывод каждый раз при добавлении и удалении вот тут уже задача.

Comment: пробую сделать массив получилось следующее (в "text" хранится принятый из импута текст)
let arr = [];
            (text) => {
                let i = 0;
                arr[i] = 12;
                i += 1;
            };
            console.log(arr);

однако выводит в консоль пустой массив, подскажите пожалуйста в чём ошибка?

Comment: @Mark, `(text) => { let i = 0; arr[i] = 12; i += 1; }` - это что за синтаксис? И каким образом вы добавляете `text` в массив

Comment: опечатался с `arr[i] = 12;` имел ввиду `arr[i] = text` чтобы присваивать индексу массива значение полученной строки, пришёл к такой попытке основываясь на https://learn.javascript.ru/array в пункте где указано - "элементы нумеруются с нуля" там в примере указана замена или добавление значения `fruits[2] = 'Груша'; // теперь ["Яблоко", "Апельсин", "Груша"]` однако у меня так не работает

Comment: Разбирал ваш код, подск. верно ли я его понял - 
` ul.addEventListener('click', () => { 
                let target = event.target; 
                if (!target.classList.contains('fa')) return;
                 target.parentNode.remove(); 
            }); `
По клику на список запускается функция, в которой создаётся переменная в которой содержится элемент на котором сработало событие, после чего исполняется if в котором когда мы нажимаем на иконку (закр-я) возвращается элемент - сама эта иконка в переменную, после чего к этому элементу применяется определение и удаление родителя, верно?

Comment: @Mark, в `if` проверяем произошёл ли клик именно по кнопке закрытия. Иначе, если я кликну по тексту `li`, функция тоже сработает. Нам это не надо, поэтому организовываем выход из функции

Comment: С массивом немного удалось продвинуться, однако есть 1 вопрос который пока  не знаю как решить, подскажите пожалуйста. Я добавил переменную с пустым массивом вне функции (чтобы массив пополнялся и хранился), по нажатию(enter) происходит добавление значения в массив и вывод в консоль, следующее нажатие и вывод с 2 элементами в массиве и т.д., но вот как быть чтобы при закрытии вкладки из массива удалялось именно значение кот. было вписано в эту закрытую вкладку? Методы удаления и вывода я знаю вопрос как определить скрипту под каким индексом удалить текст?